# Can't install powertools on RHEL 8.5

Tags: centos, rhel, ef-power-tools

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to setup my RHEL 8.5 VM machine.

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux
VERSION="8.5 (Ootpa)
```

I'm trying to install some scripts for course, and it is giving an error that PowerTools can't be found

```
No matching repo to modify: powertools.
```

I have tried several solution in other posts as follows:

```
# dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
# dnf upgrade
# dnf -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
# dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

The first three commands execute and my system is updated but the last command is still having same error:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Error: No matching repo to modify: powertools.
```

When I try to get repolist, it is not showing powertools

```
# dnf repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
repo id                                                       repo name
BaseOS                                                        BaseOS
appstream                                                     appstream
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms                      Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
epel                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
```

I hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *no* exactly "`powertools`" in RHEL. That's a CentOS alternative name to the trademarked "CodeReady Builder" repo from RHEL.

In RHEL, you enable it like so:

```sh
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
```

If `codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms` already shows up in "yum repolist", consider that you have "powertools" already enabled, no action is needed.